# PHP: How to first log an exception and then report by mail?

Tags: php, error-handling

I just handcrafted a complex order process which will go online soon. For the first time, I want to be informed about any errors that occur, but I also want them to be logged. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276667/1060128) suggests to first log them and then mail them to be more secure since mailing might fail. But when I catch the exception, it's not being logged, and when I don't catch it, I can't send an email.

My code:

```
// convert errors to exceptions
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    // ... some code that might cause errors or throw exceptions
} catch(Exception $e) {
    log(...); // how can i make the error being logged here?
    mail(...); // afterwards i send an email
    throw $e; // i could re-throw it this way, but only after mailing it, cause it kills the process.
}
```

Sure, I could write my one logging routine, but I guess PHP already does it in a clever way which I'd like to use.

Another thing that would be great is having some control that makes sure that no more then x error emails per hour are sent out.

All in all it seems to be a pretty common setup, but I couldn't find a ready solution. Or is the idea somehow stupid in the hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)() will automatically log your message to the web server's error_log file. If you prefer, you can specify a custom log file vs. the default error_log file.

So you can log a simple error message in `error_log` like this:

```
error_log("This is my error message");
```

Or to log an exception message in `/var/log/web_error_log`:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/log/web_error_log');
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php for more details on `error_log`.